# updating the pair row based on id

Tags: vba, excel

i copy and paste 2 columns from my copySheet (Column A and B) to pasteSheet( Column A and B) to first empty row with this code;

```
Set copySheet = Worksheets("copySheet")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("pasteSheet")

lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 With copySheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
 pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   With copySheet.Range("B1:B" & lRow)
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
 End Sub
```

I want to code an algorithm to check, if in any cell of Column A of the copySheet has same values with the pasteSheets values, then the cell of Column B in pasteSheet will have the value of Column B of copysheet.

To sum up: i have to Columns in each Sheet; Column A has the id numbers and Column B has the names. During copy/paste action, if Column A of copysheet has same id number as in Column A of pasteSheet, then the pair of this id (Column B of copySheet) will be overwritten to pasteSheet'S corresponding cell in Column B.

With this, i will update the amount of the products(Column B) based on ID (Column A). I hope my question is clear and hope to get suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub AddOrUpdate()

    Dim copySheet As Worksheet, pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, rw As Long, m, v

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("copySheet")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("pasteSheet")

    lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For rw = 1 To lRow

        v = copySheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value 'id value

        'is there an id match on pastesheet Col A?
        m = Application.Match(v, pasteSheet.Columns(1), 0)

        If IsError(m) Then
            'not matched, so add as new row
            With pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Value = v
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = copySheet.Cells(rw, 2).Value
            End With
        Else
            'matched, so just update the amount
            pasteSheet.Cells(m, 2).Value = copySheet.Cells(rw, 2).Value
        End If

    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! just quick question; v = copySheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value ; 1 means here A right? If i would have a Column Called BX then it ll be corrosponding number then ?

Comment: You can use either a number or a letter as the second argument to Cells(). So Cells(rw, 1) and Cells(rw, "A") refer to the same cell.